# How many different paths are there on a lattice that pass through a given point?

Tags: combinatorics

[image]

When Looking at A to C by ${4\choose 2}$ we are ordering, right-r up-u 4 times, so ordering 2 r's or 2 u's determine the other 2 moves?
And same with C to B ${3\choose 2}$ ordering the 2 r's determine the order of the leftover u?
So in general can we conclude that for a given combination with n different elements we need to order just $n-1$ of them and the leftover will be determined?

Comment: Since you only have two options, choosing where you go right determines where you must go up.

Answer (score 1):

$\bf{Solution::}$

No. of path from $\bf{\left(A\rightarrow B\right)}$ = No. of path from $\bf{\left(A\rightarrow C\right)}$ * No. of path from $\bf{\left(C\rightarrow B\right)}$

So which is $= $ Arranging $\bf{RRUU}$+Arranging $\bf{RRU}\displaystyle  = \frac{4!}{2!\times 2!}*\frac{3!}{2!} = 6*3=18$

Here $\bf{R} = 1\; Unit $ Rightward and $\bf{U=1\;unit}$ Upward.